# Javascript format date

Tags: javascript, datetime, formatting, format

I have a date string which coming from the db as follows

> /Date(1469167371657)/

Is there any way to convert this date to following format using javascript

> MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM

I've searched a lot but unble to find a solution

Comment: you can use `date = new Date(1469167371657)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain javascript you have to write your own function for string format a date, for example for your string format:

```js
var date = new Date(1469167371657);

function stringDate(date) {
   var mm = date.getMonth()+1;
 mm = (mm<10?"0"+mm:mm);
 var dd = date.getDate();
 dd = (dd<10?"0"+dd:dd);
   var hh = date.getHours();
   hh = (hh<10?"0"+hh:hh);
   var min = date.getMinutes();
   min = (min<10?"0"+min:min);
  return mm+'/'+dd+'/'+date.getFullYear()+" "+hh+":"+min;
}

console.log(stringDate(date));
```

drier code version

```js
var date = new Date(1469167371657);

function stringDate(date) {
  return ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)+'/'
     +("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2)+'/'
     +date.getFullYear()+" "
     +("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2)+':'
     +("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2)
}

console.log(stringDate(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

with pure js you can do the folowing

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use - http://momentjs.com/ and have it done like:

```
moment(1469167371657).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that number is milliseconds so to convert it to date, you would do this:

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
var date = new Date(time);
alert(date.toString()); // Wed Jan 12 2011 12:42:46 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

```js
var time=1469167371657;
var date = new Date(time);
alert(date.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following steps:

1) convert the timestamp to a date object.

```
var timestamp = "/Date(1469167371657)/"; // However you want to save whatever comes from your database
timestamp = timestamp.substr(timestamp.indexOf("(")+1); // gives 1469167371657)/
timestamp = timestamp.substr(0,timestamp.indexOf(")")); // gives 1469167371657
var d = new Date(timestamp);
```

2) set it to your format

```
function leadZero(i) {if(i < 10) {return "0"+i;} return i;} // Simple function to convert 5 to 05 e.g.
var time = leadZero(d.getMonth()+1)+"/"+leadZero(d.getDate())+"/"+d.getFullYear()+" "+leadZero(d.getHours())+":"+leadZero(d.getMinutes());
alert(time);
```

**Note: the date / timestamp you provided is too high for javascript to understand, so this example will not work correclty**